# xiaomi android 7: JobIntentService.onHandleWork() runs in a loop

Tags: java, android, jobintentservice

I am working with `JobIntentService` class that does some background work:

```
public class JsInvokerJobService extends JobIntentService {
    /**
     * Unique job ID for this service.
     */
    static final int JOB_ID = 1000;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "AppsAndJunk";
    private static final String TAG = "JsInvokerJobService";


    /**
     * Convenience method for enqueuing work in to this service.
     */
    static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
        enqueueWork(context, JsInvokerJobService.class, JOB_ID, work);
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        ...
    }

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(final Intent intent) {
        createNotificationChannel();
        Log.i(TAG, "Executing work: " + intent);

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Inside runnable " + intent);
                JsInvokerJobService.this.startService(intent);
            }
        });

        Log.i(TAG, "Finished work: " + intent);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "All work complete");
    }


}
```

and this is how work is enqueued for this class:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, JsInvokerService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra("intentAction", intentAction);
serviceIntent.putExtra("intentData", intentData);
if(originalIntentExtras != null) {
    serviceIntent.putExtras(originalIntentExtras);
}
JsInvokerJobService.enqueueWork(context, serviceIntent);
```

This works perfectly on my Samsung Android 9. In the logs I see this for every job:

```
09-30 11:31:03.599 10650 10924 I JsInvokerJobService: Executing work: Intent { cmp=com.smartsecurityxzt/.JsInvokerJobService (has extras) }
09-30 11:31:03.599 10650 10924 I JsInvokerJobService: Finished work: Intent { cmp=com.smartsecurityxzt/.JsInvokerJobService (has extras) }
09-30 11:31:03.599 10650 10650 I JsInvokerJobService: Inside runnable Intent { cmp=com.smartsecurityxzt/.JsInvokerJobService (has extras) }
09-30 11:31:03.607 10650 10650 I JsInvokerJobService: All work complete
```

but when I test this out on Xiaomi Android 7, I see that this `onHandleWork` method is called indefinitely:

```
09-30 11:31:03.599 10650 10924 I JsInvokerJobService: Executing work: Intent { cmp=com.smartsecurityxzt/.JsInvokerJobService (has extras) }
09-30 11:31:03.599 10650 10924 I JsInvokerJobService: Finished work: Intent { cmp=com.smartsecurityxzt/.JsInvokerJobService (has extras) }
09-30 11:31:03.599 10650 10650 I JsInvokerJobService: Inside runnable Intent { cmp=com.smartsecurityxzt/.JsInvokerJobService (has extras) }
09-30 11:31:03.607 10650 10650 I JsInvokerJobService: All work complete
09-30 11:31:03.610 10650 10700 I JsInvokerJobService: Executing work: Intent { cmp=com.smartsecurityxzt/.JsInvokerJobService (has extras) }
09-30 11:31:03.611 10650 10700 I JsInvokerJobService: Finished work: Intent { cmp=com.smartsecurityxzt/.JsInvokerJobService (has extras) }
09-30 11:31:03.611 10650 10650 I JsInvokerJobService: Inside runnable Intent { cmp=com.smartsecurityxzt/.JsInvokerJobService (has extras) }
09-30 11:31:03.619 10650 10650 I JsInvokerJobService: All work complete
09-30 11:31:03.623 10650 10784 I JsInvokerJobService: Executing work: Intent { cmp=com.smartsecurityxzt/.JsInvokerJobService (has extras) }
09-30 11:31:03.623 10650 10784 I JsInvokerJobService: Finished work: Intent { cmp=com.smartsecurityxzt/.JsInvokerJobService (has extras) }
09-30 11:31:03.623 10650 10650 I JsInvokerJobService: Inside runnable Intent { cmp=com.smartsecurityxzt/.JsInvokerJobService (has extras) }
09-30 11:31:03.630 10650 10650 I JsInvokerJobService: All work complete
09-30 11:31:03.633 10650 10703 I JsInvokerJobService: Executing work: Intent { cmp=com.smartsecurityxzt/.JsInvokerJobService (has extras) }
09-30 11:31:03.633 10650 10703 I JsInvokerJobService: Finished work: Intent { cmp=com.smartsecurityxzt/.JsInvokerJobService (has extras) }
09-30 11:31:03.634 10650 10650 I JsInvokerJobService: Inside runnable Intent { cmp=com.smartsecurityxzt/.JsInvokerJobService (has extras) }
09-30 11:31:03.639 10650 10650 I JsInvokerJobService: All work complete
...
```

why is that? How do I stop this?